# MySQL documentation clarification; trigger accessing another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Does this mean I can't update another table from a trigger if I'm using MySQL < 5.0.10

[MySQL documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

> Note Before MySQL 5.0.10, triggers cannot contain direct references to
>   tables by name. Beginning with MySQL 5.0.10, you can write triggers
>   such as the one named testref shown in this example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. [This FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9) states this fact in a less ambiguous way:

> Before MySQL 5.0.10, a trigger cannot modify other tables

Please note [the following limitation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9) still exists in v5.5 and v5.6:

> A trigger (...) is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.